# looking for s3cmd download command for a certain date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, s3cmd

I am trying to figure out on what the s3cmd command would be to download files from bucket by date, so for example i have a bucket named "test" and in that bucket there are different files from different dates. I am trying to get the files that were uploaded yesterday. what would the command be?

Comment: How is the bucket/folder organized? Is it flat or by the date?

Comment: File, Size, Type, Last Modified(year-month-date, hour-minute-seconds), Sotrage Class

Comment: if your bucket structure is organized according to dates it is possible to iterate over the folder structure and retrieve the files. ( This is the case in AWS S3 CloudTrail logs)

Answer (score 2):

There is no single command that will allow you to do that. You have to write a script some thing like this. Or use a SDK that allows you to do this. Below script is a sample script that will get S3 files from last 30 days.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: ./getOld "bucketname" "30 days"
s3cmd ls s3://$1 | while read -r line;  do

createDate=`echo $line|awk {'print $1" "$2'}`
createDate=`date -d"$createDate" +%s`
olderThan=`date -d"-$2" +%s`
if [[ $createDate -lt $olderThan ]]
  then 
    fileName=`echo $line|awk {'print $4'}`
    echo $fileName
    if [[ $fileName != "" ]]
      then
        s3cmd get "$fileName"
    fi
fi
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

I like s3cmd but to work with single line command, I prefer the JSon output of aws cli and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) JSon processor

The command will look like

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket "yourbucket" |\
jq '.Contents[] | select(.LastModified | startswith("yourdate")).Key' --raw-output |\
xargs -I {} aws s3 cp s3://yourbucket/{} .
```

basically what the script does

1. list all object from a given bucket
2. (the interesting part) jq will parse the `Contents` array and select element where the `LastModified` value start with your pattern (you will need to change), get the `Key` of the s3 object and add `--raw-output` so it strips the quote from the value
3. pass the result to an aws copy command to download the file from s3

if you want to automate a bit further you can get yesterday from the command line

for mac os

```
$ export YESTERDAY=`date -v-1w +%F`
$ aws s3api list-objects --bucket "ariba-install" |\
jq '.Contents[] | select(.LastModified | startswith('\"$YESTERDAY\"')).Key' --raw-output |\
xargs -I {} aws s3 cp s3://ariba-install/{} .
```

for linux os (or other flavor of bash that I am not familiar)

```
$ export YESTERDAY=`date -d "1 day ago" '+%Y-%m-%d' `
$ aws s3api list-objects --bucket "ariba-install" |\
jq '.Contents[] | select(.LastModified | startswith('\"$YESTERDAY\"')).Key' --raw-output |\
xargs -I {} aws s3 cp s3://ariba-install/{} .
```

Now you get the idea if you want to change the `YESTERDAY` variable to have different kind of date